# Separate Strings with quotes around them from strings without in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string from a database field thats like this i bring into a varible words:

```
 spaceship cars boats "subway train" rocket bicycle "18 wheeler"
```

if i do a split on string with this:

```
words = string.split()
```

I get results like this:

```
['spaceship', 'cars', 'boats', "'subway", "train'", 'rocket', 'bicycle', "'18", "wheeler'"]
```

what I would like is to split it to a list with the quoted words in tact so the list would look like this:

```
['spaceship', 'cars', 'boats', "'subway train'", 'rocket', 'bicycle', "'18 wheeler'"]
```

Is there a way tto processes this this way in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) module:

```
>>> x
'spaceship cars boats "subway train" rocket bicycle "18 wheeler"'
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split(x)
['spaceship', 'cars', 'boats', 'subway train', 'rocket', 'bicycle', '18 wheeler']
```

Another solution would be using `regex` in this form:

```
import re
re.split(your_regular_exp, x)
```

but this is not as simple as with shlex but may prove usefull in other cases!

Answer (score 1):

I think CSV is probably your friend here.

```
import csv
row = 'spaceship cars boats "subway train" rocket bicycle "18 wheeler"'
reader = csv.reader([row], delimiter=' ')
words = next(reader)
```